# Missing Layout and Data Frame Buttons in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, user-interface

I have lost the Layout and Data Frame Buttons at the bottom of my map window in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1. How can I get them back?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, this is a really simple fix and I found the answer on [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/18923).

In the View menu, select Scroll Bars.

[image]

In addition to turning on scroll bars, this turns on the Layout, Data Frame, Refresh and Pause buttons.

[image]