# Bottom Scroll Bar, View Selection, and Refresh/Pause Missing

Tags: arcmap

Admins might at first think this is a repeat question, but it isn't. The other question similar to this issue specifies that the bottom scroll bar goes missing in ***layout*** view. This problem is occurring in ***both*** layout and data view. I have gone to the View menu > Scroll Bars and made sure it is selected. I've even tried deselecting and reselecting it, to no avail. However, if I go into the View menu and select Layout View, the scroll bar appears. Usually, it will remain, but it sometimes will disappear again after a period of time. I'm using ArcMap 10.5.1 on an enterprise system.

Comment: Since you've checked View -> Scroll Bars, which is normally the [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273831/7424) to this problem, I would say there is something corrupt in your installation of ArcMap. I suggest doing a reinstall or repair.